# track form changes when user leaving page/refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I have a form which is written using formik and react-hooks. I am trying get recommendations on how to track a form change when user clicks home button or page refresh/reload?

I have tried, browser history method to trigger a modal to show unsaved changes
`const unlisten = browserHistory.listen( location =>  {
            //trigger modal here
           });`
But this seems to doesn't work. Also I am using react-router...if any suggestions using that will be helpful.
I am all done storing formvalues into a state using useState and setState, 
I have a modal to show when exit button is clicked on form to track form changes but I am not sure how to detect outside of form.

Comment: Did you try `localStorage` ?

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia localStorage is taking values as string only but my form values are stored in object.

Comment: You can use `localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(yourObject));` 
Or store items individually

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia I have tried that but that is unable to track the changes on form.

Comment: Did you use `JSON.parse`?
Parse those when getting the items `const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('miItem'))`

Answer (score 0):

I will put this here as a posible workaround to the question.

When you update your form in your handleChange method (whatever it is),you can also update user localstorage. With this approach you can check when page loads if there is some values in storage from older sessions or before.

Setting Values:

```
this.setState({ item1: value }, () => {
  localStorage.setItem('myForm', JSON.stringify(this.state));
});
```

Getting values:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const storedValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myForm'))
  this.setState({...storedValues});
}
```

Restore Data:
In your onSubmit method remember to clear localStorage

```
localStorage.removeItem('myForm');
```

Comment: I am using function functional component where I have written `useEffect(() => window.sessionStorage.setItem("values", JSON.stringify(formPayLoad)), [formPayLoad]); `... formik values are unable to retrieve outside of form component.

Comment: I never used formik, i think you can get it without it

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [react-router-navigation-prompt](https://github.com/ZacharyRSmith/react-router-navigation-prompt) for exactly that purpose, it's made for react router. Just add this component inside your `<Form/>` / `<form/>`,

```
<NavigationPrompt
   when={formProps.dirty}>
      {({ isActive, onConfirm, onCancel }) => {
          if (isActive) {
            return (
              <ConfirmationPopUp
                 isOpen
                 onConfirm={onConfirm}
                 onCancel={onCancel}
                />
                 );
               }
             }}
 </NavigationPrompt>
```